# How to retrieve specific field using Specification in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, specifications

> I am using JpaSpecificationExecutor in spring boot but I am not able
> to get single column or selected column list,
> for example SQL query is "Select firstname,lastname from student where firstname='abc';"
> I am facing issue with JpaSpecificationExecutor it always gives whole entity.
>
> ```
>         My some code added
>         Repository Interface
> ```

````
    ```    
    @Repository
        public interface PolicyRepository extends JpaRepository<Policy, Long>,JpaSpecificationExecutor<Policy> {    
        }
    
    public class PredicateSpecification<T> implements Specification<T> {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            SearchCriteria search_criteria;
            public PredicateSpecification(SearchCriteria criteria) {
                this.search_criteria = criteria;
            }
            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
                List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
                switch (search_criteria.getOperation()) {
                case GREATER_THAN:
                    predicates.add(builder.greaterThan(root.get(search_criteria.getKey()).as(String.class),
                            builder.literal(search_criteria.getValue().toString())));
                    break;
                case LESS_THAN:
                    predicates.add(builder.lessThan(root.get(search_criteria.getKey()).as(String.class),
                            builder.literal(search_criteria.getValue().toString())));
                    break;
                case GREATER_THAN_EQUAL:
                    predicates.add(builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get(search_criteria.getKey()).as(String.class),
                            builder.literal(search_criteria.getValue().toString())));
                    break;
                case LESS_THAN_EQUAL:
                    predicates.add(builder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get(search_criteria.getKey()).as(String.class),
                            builder.literal(search_criteria.getValue().toString())));
                    
                    break;
                case NOT_EQUAL:
                    predicates.add(builder.notEqual(root.get(search_criteria.getKey()), search_criteria.getValue()));
                    break;
                case EQUAL:
                    predicates.add(builder.equal(root.get(search_criteria.getKey()), search_criteria.getValue()));
                    break;
                case MATCH:
                    predicates.add(builder.like(builder.lower(root.get(search_criteria.getKey())),
                            "%" + search_criteria.getValue().toString().toLowerCase() + "%"));
                    break;
                case MATCH_END:
                    predicates.add(builder.like(builder.lower(root.get(search_criteria.getKey())),
                            search_criteria.getValue().toString().toLowerCase() + "%"));
                    break;
                case MATCH_START:
                    predicates.add(builder.like(builder.lower(root.get(search_criteria.getKey())),
                            "%" + search_criteria.getValue().toString().toLowerCase()));
                    break;
                case IN:
            predicates.add(builder.in(root.get(search_criteria.getKey())).value(search_criteria.getValue()));
                    break;
                case ORDER_BY:
                    if (search_criteria.getValue().equals(OrderBy.ASC)) {
                        query.orderBy(builder.asc(root.get(search_criteria.getKey())));
                    } else if (search_criteria.getValue().equals(OrderBy.DESC)) {
                        query.orderBy(builder.desc(root.get(search_criteria.getKey())));
                    }
                    break;
                case GROUP_BY:
                    query.groupBy(root.get(search_criteria.getKey()));
                    // query.multiselect(root.get(search_criteria.getKey()), builder.count(root));
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
                return builder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
            }
        }
public List<Policy> getPolicyByPredicates() throws ParseException {
                PredicateSpecification<Policy> psf1 = new PredicateSpecification<Policy>(
                    (new SearchCriteria("policyName", "test", SearchOperation.MATCH)));
            PredicateSpecification<Policy> psf2 = new PredicateSpecification<Policy>(
                    (new SearchCriteria("isEnable",true, SearchOperation.EQUAL)));
                return policyRepo.findAll(Specification.where(psf1).and(psf2));
        }
    ```
above getPolicyByPredicates() method call from controller
and it returns List<Policy> but I want to return only specific columns.
````

How it is possible to return specific column from entity using jpa specification?
Please Help Me.

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

Could you please elaborate or give example what you mean by 'get single column or selected column list'.  The result of your query will mapped based on your defined Policy entity. If you want to get a specific property from your List, you may use 'Map' from a stream after calling your getPolicyByPredicates() method.

Example:

```
List<Policy> result = getPolicyByPredicates();
List<String> lastNames = result.stream()
                           .map(Policy::getLastName)
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The example above only shows getting the 'lastNames' but still you can select which column you want to get.

Comment: Actullay in specification execute query like "select * from policy where pname="abc" "   but if i want to create query like "select pname,lastname,isenable from policy where pname="abc" " then how can do?

Comment: and I am facing another issue that is, select * from tablename it gives unnecessary child table info.                                                                                                                          for example  in case of  one parent has many childs i.e onetomany relationship  in Parent-Child table,and if we exceute query using jpa specification it retrives parent as well as child table data,and i think this gives performance issue in large data,So how can resolve this issue in JPA Specification.